# Setting up WiFi with new Sonicwall across existing network

Tags: routing, cisco-catalyst, sonicwall

I am trying to set up a new WiFi AP in our HR building.  There is a closet in the HR building, with a switch connected by fiber to our main network closet, then to another network closet where the FiOS is at.

I set up a "no switchport" interface on the switch that is directly connected to the Sonicwall with IP 10.0.8.247.  I've created the VLAN on our VTP server switch, and I created the route on the switch directly connected to the Sonicwall.

From the switch in the HR building I am able to ping the 10.0.8.247 interface, but not the Sonicwall interface of 10.0.8.1, and I am able to ping the Sonicwall from the directly connected switch.  I've included a map of how I have it set up, still very new with Cisco and have been struggling with this for a few days.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Middle Switch](http://pastebin.com/mXJrtDWp)
[Bottom Switch](http://pastebin.com/bQLGJm34)

[image: Network Map]

Comment: It sounds like you have the 10.0.8.0 network split into two vlans, but we can't be sure without more information.  Can you post the configurations of all three switches?

Comment: There really isn't enough detail here to provide an answer, consider [adding more detail](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33). To start, is there any particular reason you have set the Fa0/24 on the second 3560 in your diagram to `no switchport`?  Leave it as an access port in VLAN 80 just like you did on  Fa0/22 on the first 3560.  Which device is providing the L3 routing on the network?  Can you provide (sanitized) configurations?

Comment: Not enough rep to post 3 links, here is top switch [Top Switch](http://pastebin.com/Up4w18gE)

Changed the port on the bottom switch to an access port.